# Tensorflow: printing graph nodes

Tags: python, tensorflow

What is the difference of printing graph nodes between these 2 methods?
Seems the printed order of ops is different.

```
def print_graph_v1():
    with open(input_model_filepath, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

        for node in graph_def.node:
            print('-'*60)
            print(node.name)

def print_graph_v2():
    with tf.gfile.GFile(input_model_filepath, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

    for op in graph.get_operations():
        print('-' * 60)
        print(op.name)
```